# Translate OpenLayers map from e.g. English to German

Tags: javascript, geolocation, internationalization, openlayers

these days I am trying to translate my OpenLayers map from English to e.g. German. The map language should be based on the site language.
However, I only find outdated blog entries for OL v2 or none at all.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Translate-Translate.html sounds mostly what I need but I don't get it working.

```
import Translate from 'ol/interaction/Translate';
Translate.set('es');
```

leads to the following console error:
`ol_interaction_Translate__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.default.set is not a function`
I admit the above `set` was more like try 'n error but the most promising I could come up with so far. I am very much stuck.

I highly appreciate leads such as examples or links to up to date blog entries. Thanks in advance!

AMartinNo1

Answer (score 2):

I highly appreciate your efforts on this cause, but i fear you got several misconceptions about 'translating'.

First, i suppose you want to set the language of the labels in the map, right (like 'Germany', 'Berlin', 'Rhein', etc)? In this case, you need to chose a fitting WMS, OSM has a ['German Style'](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/German_Style), which not only has all the labels all over the world in German, but also the styling is based on the german Shell Atlas. 
If you only need map data for Germany, the german [WebAtlas](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=4&gdz_anz_zeile=4&gdz_unt_zeile=0&gdz_user_id=0) is the go-to choice for many.

Second (just for the future or anyone else reading this), 'translate' in geography does not mean 'translating the language', it means 'moving something without changing it's shape' (*verschieben* in german), that's also the reason why it's at *interaction* in the OpenLayers library.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I mean to have the labels translated. It's good to know that Translating has a different meaning. This clarify things :)

Answer (score 2):

To make a map fully international you would probably need to use a vector source, at least for the labels.  This example doesn't need an API key, but Mapbox and MapTiler provide similar services.

```js
var language = document.getElementById('language')

var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
  color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
});
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: '#3399CC',
  width: 1.25
});
var styles = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'black',
        width: 1.25
      }),
      radius: 5
    }),
    fill: fill,
    stroke: stroke,
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      font: '18px Calibri,sans-serif',
      textBaseline: 'top',
      offsetY: 4
    })
  })
];

var res10;
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 45]),
    zoom: 2
  }),
  layers: [new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
      url: 'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf',
    }),
    style: function(feature, resolution) {
      var type = feature.get('layer');
      var marine = (resolution < res10);
      if ((type == 'Coastline' && !marine) ||
          (type == 'Marine area' && marine) ||
          type.indexOf('City') == 0 ||
          (type.indexOf('Water area') == 0 && feature.getGeometry().getType() != 'Point')) {
        styles[0].getText().setText(feature.get('_name_' + language.value));
        return styles;
      }
    },
    declutter : true
  })]
});
res10 = map.getView().getResolutionForZoom(7);

language.onchange = function() {
  map.getLayers().item(0).getSource().refresh();
};
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <select id="language">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
    <option value="zh_h">Chinese (Hong Kong)</option>
    <option value="zh_s">Chinese (Modern)</option>
    <option value="zh_t">Chinese (Taiwan)</option>
    <option value="cs">Czech</option>
    <option value="fi">Finnish</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
    <option value="de">German</option>
    <option value="he">Hebrew</option>
    <option value="it">Italian</option>
    <option value="ja">Japanese</option>
    <option value="ko">Korean</option>
    <option value="pl">Polish</option>
    <option value="pt_b">Portugese (Brazil)</option>
    <option value="ru">Russian</option>
    <option value="es">Spanish</option>
    <option value="sv">Swedish</option>
    <option value="tr">Turkish</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I will check it out latest at weekend as it's a spare time project :)

Comment: Just had time to check it out on my working machine. Looks neat. Need to check how to use that with my source. I use some js import with alias. I guess will continue first with digging more into OSM etc. to get a better understanding. So, won't mark this as solution thus it's very promising.